# What is the proper way to declare an event handler with arguments for a tclientdataset component at runtime

Tags: delphi, events, tclientdataset

I am attempting to define a ClientDataSet component in a form at runtime.  I can successfully define all the fields and operate the ClientDataSet in the VCL form program, however when I attempt to add an event handler for events such as AfterInsert to the code, the compiler objects to my format.

The clientDataset is created in this procedure:

```
procedure TForm1.CreateNestedDataSets;
begin

  cdsTables := TClientDataSet.Create(Self);
  cdsNotes := TClientDataSet.Create(cdsTables); //nested dataset
  //Define Tables
  with TFloatField.Create(Self) do
  begin
    Name := 'TblID';
    FieldKind := fkData;
    FieldName := 'ID';
    DataSet := cdsTables;
    Required := True;
  end;

  ...  //define other fields for cdsTables  & nested clientdataset cdsNotes

  cdsNotes.AfterInsert := cdsNotesAfterInsert(cdsNotes: TDataSet);

  //Create the ClientDataSet and its nested datasets
  cdsTables.CreateDataSet;

  //This is problem code line:
  cdsNotes.AfterInsert := cdsNotesAfterInsert;


  //Configure the DataSources
  dsTables.DataSet := cdsTables;
  dsNotes.DataSet := cdsNotes;
end;
```

Various forum discussions have suggested approaches such as this example:

```
MyLabel := TLabel.Create(self);
MyLabel.OnClick := MyLabelClick;
```

In the case of AfterInsert there is an argument included.  If I generate the event at design time, Delphi generates:

```
procedure TForm1.ClientDataSet1AfterInsert(DataSet: TDataSet);
```

Attempting to duplicate the suggestion above I tried this approach which generates a compiler error:

`cdsNotes.AfterInsert := cdsNotesAfterInsert;`  Incompatible types parameter list differs

Other formats also generate errors:

`cdsNotes.AfterInsert := cdsNotesAfterInsert(DataSet: TDataSet);`  Too many actual parameters

I have tried other variations withan assorment of error messages. This is my first attempt at defining an event and I am not certain I understand how to handle the declaration. I beleive the actual procedure I declare to implement the event 'cdsNotesAfterInsert' does not require any parameter since it is tied
to the clientdataset cdsNotes. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Here is a complete form unit with the offending code

```
    unit ForumTest;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Data.DB, DBClient;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    cdsTables : tclientDataset;
    cdsNotes :tclientDataset;
    procedure CreateNestedDataSets;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
procedure TForm1.CreateNestedDataSets;
begin

  cdsTables := TClientDataSet.Create(Self);
  cdsNotes := TClientDataSet.Create(cdsTables);
  //Define Tables
  with TFloatField.Create(Self) do
  begin
    Name := 'TblID';
    FieldKind := fkData;
    FieldName := 'ID';
    DataSet := cdsTables;
    Required := True;
  end;
  with TFloatField.Create(Self) do
  begin
    Name := 'TblParentID';
    FieldKind := fkData;
    FieldName := 'Parent';
    DataSet := cdsTables;
    Required := false;
  end;
  with TStringField.Create(Self) do
  begin
    Name := 'TblTitle';
    FieldKind := fkData;
    FieldName := 'Title';
    Size := 40;
    DataSet := cdsTables;
    Required := True;
  end;
  with TStringField.Create(Self) do
  begin
    Name := 'TblFilename';
    FieldKind := fkData;
    FieldName := 'Filename';
    Size := 80;
    DataSet := cdsTables;
    Required := False;
  end;
  //Note: For TDataSetFields, FieldKind is fkDataSet by default
  with TDataSetField.Create(Self) do
  begin
    Name := 'TblNotes';
    FieldName := 'NestedDataSet';
    DataSet := cdsTables;
  end;

  //Define Notes
  cdsNotes.DataSetField := TDataSetField(FindComponent('TblNotes'));
  with TFloatField.Create(Self) do
  begin
    Name := 'NoteID';
    FieldKind := fkData;
    FieldName := 'Note ID';
    DataSet := cdsNotes;
    Required := True;
  end;
  with TStringField.Create(Self) do
  begin
    Name := 'NoteTxt';
    FieldKind := fkData;
    FieldName := 'Notes';
    DataSet := cdsNotes;
    Size := 40;
  end;
  cdsNotes.AfterInsert := cdsNotesAfterInsert(cdsNotes: TDataSet);
  //Create the ClientDataSet and its nested datasets
  cdsTables.CreateDataSet;
  //Configure the DataSources
  dsTables.DataSet := cdsTables;
  dsNotes.DataSet := cdsNotes;

end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CreateNestedDataSets;
end;

end.
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  Please clarify. I am not sure what else to provide, I have included the offending procedure. Everything works until I try to declare an event.  I am getting the format wrong in the declaration.  Like most programs the full form code is quite large and not relevant to the question.

Comment: I added code for a complete form that produces the error

Comment: `cdsNotes.AfterInsert := cdsNotesAfterInsert;` is the correct syntax but you did not define `cdsNotesAfterInsert`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  I tried your comment  in my sample and got errors. If I declare a procedure  cdsNotesAfterInsert  at the unit level I get 'Incompatible types method pointer & Regular procedure'.  If I declare it in the form public section I get error 'parameter types differ'.

Comment: Your cdsNotesAfterInsert needs to be a method of your TForm1 so that is a `procedure of object` and therefore assignment-compatible with the `.AfterInsert` event handler.  Do that and your problem will go away.

Comment: @MartynA  I have declared 'procedure `cdsNotesAfterInsert;` in the public section of the Tform1 declaration and provided a procedure `tform1.cdsNotesAfterInsert;` in the unit's implementation and get the error parameter types differ.  Am I missing something?

Comment: What's missing  is the [mcve]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is specifically to answer your point about how to assign some self-written code to a TClientDataSet's AfterInsert event property.

If you look up TClientDataSet.AfterInsert in the online help, you'll see that it is defined as a TDataSetNotifyEvent,  which in turn is defined as

```
type TDataSetNotifyEvent = procedure(DataSet: TDataSet) of object
```

The significance of the `of object` is that the procedure must be a method of an object (for which read "class"), **not** a stand-alone procedure/method as you seemed to be describing in a comment.

To be assignment-compatible with a TDataSetNotifyEvent, your procedure needs to have a matching code "signature ", that is, it must be a procedure of a class (not a function of a class) and have the exact same parameters, in this case a single TDataSet parameter.

So pulling that all together, all you need is something like

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    procedure MyInsertHandler(ADataSet : TDataSet);
  end;

[...]

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientDataSet1.AfterInsert := MyInsertHandler;
end;

procedure TForm1.MyInsertHandler(ADataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  // Your code goes here, e.g.
  Caption := ADataSet.Name + ' after insert';
end;
```

Simple as that.

Comment: Well that worked! I had the declaration correctly placed in the TForm1 class definition, but did not have the `(ADataset : TDataset)` arguments properly included in the declaration.  I kept trying to include the arguments in the FormCreate code line :(